# How to get the Radwindow from a page in wpf

Tags: c#, telerik, wpf-controls

My application has many pages inside `Radwindow`. in code behind of the page, how can I get the Radwindow. eg: I want to change `Radwindow's` title,...

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
var wnd = RadWindow.GetParentRadWindow(this);
```